# Undo within a modal dialog

Tags: forms, undo

We're having a debate about how "Undo" should operate, specifically within a modal dialog box (on a desktop platform).

What I see generally in applications is that each individual control (text box generally) has its own "undo". So if you type a change into a text box, then press Ctrl-Z it undoes the change to that text box.

What I've never seen is an Undo chain that spans multiple entry fields in the dialog. So to explain:

- User makes changes to field A
- User makes a change to a different field, B
- User presses Ctrl-Z. Change to field B is undone.
- User presses Ctrl-Z again. Focus changes to field A and change to that is undone.

This might be what you expect within an "editor" (the "project properties" editor of a C# project within Visual Studio does this for example), something with a "save" model, but doesn't feel like what I'd expect within a modal dialog with an "ok"/"cancel" model. However I can't find any UX guidelines that back my feeling up (or indeed contradict it).

It perhaps depends on how complex the dialog is. Clearly for a simple dialog, just cancelling the dialog gets you out of trouble, or using a "reset" button for example, something along those lines.

Is there a good principal to apply here, a "normal" behaviour? 
Are there any documented UX design principles I can reference that might cover this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would enable the undo functionality inside the modal. The way I see it, when the it is open, everything behind it freezes and all edits only apply to the modal. Please make sure you test this with your users and see if they expect this functionality.